# Keras hyperparameter tuning error: ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 10 and 20 for '{{node mean_absolute_error/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FL

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, forecast

I am trying to do hyperparameter tuning for my forecasting model. I am trying to forecast the next 20 values by looking previous 10 values. So x_train's shape is (571, 10, 1), Y_Train's shape is (571, 20, 1). When I do model.fit with those values it's accepted. But when i try to do :

```
tuner.search(train_data_multi,epochs=20,batch_size=64)
```

It's throwing me this error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 10 and 20 for '{{node mean_absolute_error/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential/dense/BiasAdd, Cast)' with input shapes: [?,10,35], [?,20,1].
```

And this is how am i preparing my data:

```
batch_size = 64
buffer_size = 1000

train_data_multi = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train_multi, y_train_multi))
train_data_multi = train_data_multi.cache().shuffle(buffer_size).batch(batch_size)

val_data_multi = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val_multi, y_val_multi))
val_data_multi = val_data_multi.batch(batch_size)

test_data_multi = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test_multi, y_test_multi))
test_data_multi = test_data_multi.batch(batch_size)

print(train_data_multi)
print(x_train_multi.shape)
```

My model:

```
EPOCHS = 500
steps = int( np.ceil(x_train_multi.shape[0] / batch_size) )
val_steps=int( np.ceil(x_val_multi.shape[0] / batch_size) )

from keras.layers import Dropout

multi_step_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
multi_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,input_shape=x_train_multi.shape[-2:],activation=None,return_sequences=True))
multi_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128,input_shape=x_train_multi.shape[-2:],activation=None,return_sequences=True))
multi_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128,input_shape=x_train_multi.shape[-2:],activation=None,return_sequences=True))
multi_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,input_shape=x_train_multi.shape[-2:],activation=None,return_sequences=False))
multi_step_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
multi_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20)) # for 72 outputs

multi_step_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(clipvalue=1.0), loss='mae')

multi_step_model.summary()
multi_step_history = multi_step_model.fit(train_data_multi, epochs=EPOCHS,
                                          steps_per_epoch=steps,
                                          validation_data=val_data_multi,
                                          validation_steps=val_steps)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56302370/7792580 and see if that helps?

Comment: @AshwinPhadke I checked it. But as i said problem only happens at keras.search, my .fit() doesnt have any problem.

Comment: Is this keras tuner that you are talking about here?

Comment: @AshwinPhadke yes.

Comment: In that case it is hard to tell just from this code what's going wrong. From what I can understand it is a layer issue rather than the tuner and it would be much harder to know what it is based on what you have shared as there's no model or reproducible code that the can be looked at and checked. If you could share the fully reproducible code I believe someone would be able to help you.

Comment: @AshwinPhadke rest of the code is doing nothing. Just parsing data and creating model. I posted my model.